# what is error Warning in .\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php#226 Cannot use a scalar value as an array in mysql using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

i want to use xampp and phpmyadmin just use mysql in university project i dont use php code and other think just i run xampp and open phpmyadmin in localhost and i got this error:

> Warning in .\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php#226
>       Cannot use a scalar value as an array
>
> Backtrace
>
> .\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php#67: 
>         PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin- 
>   setSessionAccessTime()
>        .\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php#248: 
>         PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->storeCredentials()
>        .\libraries\common.inc.php#351: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin- 
>   authenticate()
>       .\index.php#27: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)

Comment: I suspect you're using a version of PhpMyAdmin that's not compatible with your version of PHP.

Comment: I got mysql and php together with xampp

Comment: But what about PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Same with xampp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i think the error was caused because of cached session. i had the same issue and clicking the logout button on the top left automatically solve the issue.

Comment: That is the write answer. It should get green tick.

Comment: Yes, the same happened to me and I did the same. Just log out and it fixed.

Comment: My phpMyAdmin crashed on import tables and using logout everything works well

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to phpmyadmin trying to load data from cache.To fix this issue clear your cache. The best method is to download ccleaner from https://www.ccleaner.com/ (free version is enough). Stop and quit xampp run "clean your pc" in c cleaner. (close all browsers)
restart xampp and your good to go.